# How to get mouse state while handling WM_MOUSEACTIVATE in wndproc

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wndproc

To prevent switching to window on left click I am handling [WM_MOUSEACTIVATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mouseactivate) and it works unless I am testing for mouse button state. The button state here will show as Released even though left button down is used to call this event and held.

```
private const int WM_MOUSEACTIVATE = 0x0021;
private const uint MA_NOACTIVATE = 3;
private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    if (msg == WM_MOUSEACTIVATE)
    {
        if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            handled = true;
            return (IntPtr)MA_NOACTIVATE ;
```

The `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` is received only after the `WM_MOUSEACTIVATE`, and I expected that static `Mouse.LeftButton` would return the current value regardless. Is there a better way to get a current state of the mouse left button?

Comment: Since you get the `WM_MOUSEACTIVATE` message before `WM_LBUTTONUP`, the button is always considered to be pressed when this happens, isn't it? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to use WndProc at all. You can use a [UIElement.PreviewMouseDown Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.previewmousedown) and refer to the [MouseButtonEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.mousebuttoneventargs) to get the state information.